# django python execute mssql query and print to web page

Tags: python, html, django, mssql-jdbc

Is there any way to execute MsSql query by django-python and print result to web page?
I want to write a script to watch ACS logs on web browser. Im already have a SQL query that returns some last logs and I want to watch logs on web page with dynamic  update information

Comment: did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raw sql queries in Django : [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries)

It's upto you to return the query result to the webpage via the views.
If you have no Model that matches the query result , you can execute and return a unmapped row as of [Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Comment: I need to connect to remote server and execute sql query on it. Raw queries for django sql, isnt it? How can i connect to my ms server just as client?

Comment: To connect to a ms sql server you need a third party database backend since django doesnot officially support mssql directly. [3rd parties](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend) , once you configured the db backend , you can simply connect to whetever host you want , being local or remote , it does not matter.